# vb XmlNode parse file with header

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I have an xml document that we've been parsing without issue up until a few days ago.  The file looked like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <Personnel>
  <PersonnelKey>
   <PersonnelNumber>AT71499</PersonnelNumber>
   <LastName>Thomas</LastName>
   <FirstName>Alexander</FirstName>
   <Position>F42</Position>
  </PersonnelKey>
  <PersonnelKey>
   <PersonnelNumber>KS62291</PersonnelNumber>
   <LastName>Sanders</LastName>
   <FirstName>Kristi       </FirstName>
   <Position>G18</Position>
  </PersonnelKey>
  <PersonnelKey>
   <PersonnelNumber>QA34088</PersonnelNumber>
   <LastName>Qilo</LastName>
   <FirstName>Astor</FirstName>
   <Position>Pk87</Position>
  </PersonnelKey>
 </Personnel>
```

The VB code I used to parse it looks like this.

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.Load(fileName)

For Each node As XmlNode In doc.DocumentElement
    PersonnelNumber = (node("PersonnelNumber").InnerText).ToString()
    LastName = (node("LastName").InnerText).ToString()
    FirstName = (node("FirstName").InnerText).ToString()
    Position = (node("Position").InnerText).ToString()

InsertPersonnelData(PersonnelNumber, LastName, FirstName, Position)

Next
```

This all worked without issue - every day, until the customer changed the file to the following -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<xmlhdr version='1.0' standalone='true'>
  <Personnel>
    <PersonnelKey>
      <PersonnelNumber>AT71499</PersonnelNumber>
      <LastName>Thomas</LastName>
      <FirstName>Alexander</FirstName>
      <Position>F42</Position>
    </PersonnelKey>
    <PersonnelKey>
      <PersonnelNumber>KS62291</PersonnelNumber>
      <LastName>Sanders</LastName>
      <FirstName>Kristi       </FirstName>
      <Position>G18</Position>
    </PersonnelKey>
    <PersonnelKey>
      <PersonnelNumber>QA34088</PersonnelNumber>
      <LastName>Qilo</LastName>
      <FirstName>Astor</FirstName>
      <Position>Pk87</Position>
    </PersonnelKey>
  </Personnel>
</xmlhdr>
```

The second line  is the issue.  I can manually remove it and it parses fine.  I'd like to go back clicking the button and everything load correctly versus manually manipulating the file then parsing it.  I asked the customer to remove the header but they claim another customer needs it so I can just ignore it.  So how can I "ignore" that line and parse the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the best, as there will only ever be one header, but it will get the job done:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.Load(fileName)

    For each hdr as XmlNode in doc.DocumentElement
      For Each node As XmlNode In doc.DocumentElement
          PersonnelNumber = (node("PersonnelNumber").InnerText).ToString()
          LastName = (node("LastName").InnerText).ToString()
          FirstName = (node("FirstName").InnerText).ToString()
          Position = (node("Position").InnerText).ToString()

          InsertPersonnelData(PersonnelNumber, LastName, FirstName, Position)
      Next
    Next
```

Comment: I received a NullReferenceException error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Which is the same error I received before your suggestion.

Comment: Which line? I used the sample you provided and didn't encounter any errors with the above.

Comment: I receive the error at the 

    PersonnelNumber = (node("PersonnelNumber").InnerText).ToString()

line.  It then jumps down to the catch statement to display the error message.

Comment: And you're sure the file you're testing with has the new header node? That's why I said this isn't the best as it won't play nicely if you get a mix of files with and without the header node.  But if they all have it, it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, this mornings file starts like this.

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xmlhdr standalone="true" version="1.0">
         <Personnel>
            <PersonnelKey>
               <PersonnelNumber>DW18966</PersonnelNumber>....

What are my other options to ignore that starting node?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you Red Dawn.  This method works fine for me.  The only other possibility I can think of is an empty PersonnelKey node in the file you're working with.

Comment: Any luck Red Dawn? (And btw, WOLVERINES!)

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't have a chance to address the issue today.  I had to manually do it.  Tomorrow, I will be back on it and post the results here.  Thank you for your help.   WOLVERINES!

Comment: Works like a charm.  I'm not certain what the initial problem was, but today it works without issue.  Thanks for the follow up.